# what are the most common stream ciphers algorithms?

Tags: stream-cipher

say that we have an unknown stream cipher which output bytes and which have more than 10 years of existence. What can be the most probable algorithms if we consider the most 'populars' stream cipher algorithms?

In order to find the most 'popular' stream ciphers, where can I find some statistics about the most implemented stream ciphers since 2000?

Comment: AES in CTR mode.

Comment: Sorry to say so, but I´m voting to close this question in its current form as it is way to broad;  and while it may provide ground for a lot of speculation, I don´t think we´ll ever come any closer to an answer than what @CodesInChaos already hinted at (which might very well be a perfect guess). Maybe you can enhance your question by editing it – making it *less broad* and less of a *“what do you people think”* kind of question. That would be great…

Comment: If it's *not* a block cipher in CTR or OFB mode, it's most likely RC4. There are a lot of other interesting stream cipher designs out there, but most of them are rarely seen outside specific niche applications (e.g. tiny embedded ASICs). RC4 is what you'll find in most crypto libraries.

Comment: in your opinion block ciphers in CTR/OFB mode are 'populars'? I had the feeling that they were rarely used ( some statistics may confirm this ) because they are slow.

Comment: _most popular_ doesn't necessarily mean _most implemented_.

Comment: what that could mean else? that the public loves the most?

Comment: please note: If CTR mode (a special case of OFB) is used, it may not be advertised to be used. Many AEAD modes use it implicitely (hope I spelled that right), like GCM.

Comment: @ e-sushi. "Sorry to say so, but I´m voting to close this question"... when someone starts by being sorry about doing something, it clearly demonstrates that this person silently acknowledge that he/she is doing something bad. Anyway, don't be sorry, I have stopped to consider that website as a serious source of information, looking a the answers I received which demonstrates that most people here don't know what they are talking about and are indeed self-claimed 'specialists' and 'experts'... well maybe they should start by completing their studies and get a few work experience.

Answer (score 3):

By far, RC4 is the most popular stream cipher that's been around for 10+ years.  ChaCha20 has just turned 10, and is now becoming popular, but was essentially unheard of 10 years ago.

Comment: maybe add AES-CTR to your list?

Comment: Salsa20 is relatively common as well, due to its use in NaCl and its derivatives.

Comment: @SEJPM: I deliberately left AES-CTR off the list, because it can be considered a block cipher (and also outputs 16 byte blocks, not 'bytes')

Comment: AES-CTR is certainly not a block cipher, poncho :P Maybe a block cipher mode of operation that turns the block cipher into a stream cipher. More constructively, we may want to include A5/1 but I guess it's unlikely to be the source of a ciphertext that has been found somewhere.

Comment: RC4 is 'popular' because it is in TLS/SSL but in general, do we have statistics that shows that it is the most widely used stream cipher ( like by software products for example )?

Comment: I think you mean Salsa20 (a family of 3 stream ciphers Salsa20/8, Salsa20/12, Salsa20/20) rather than ChaCha20 (the 20-round version of ChaCha), since ChaCha was published in 2008.